# contentEditable span - preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, events

Trying to stop enter from creating 
 when editing an editable span. I've tried searching but had no luck. Key presses are being detected fine, tested with alerts but just the preventDefault(); doesn't seem to work. I have searched and this seems to be the way that other people have prevented 
 from being created on enter.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.note>span', function(){ //edit notes
        var storedNote = $(this).text();
        var storedNoteIndex = notes.indexOf(storedNote);
        $(this).keyup(function (e) { //edit notes
            var newNote = $(this).text();
            if(newNote != "" && newNote != " " && newNote.charAt(0) != " ") {
                if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
                    alert('enter+shift');
                }
                else if(e.keyCode == 13){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                var newNote = $(this).text();
                notes.splice(storedNoteIndex, 1, newNote);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'notes':notes});
            }
            else{
                notes.splice(storedNoteIndex, 1);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'notes':notes});
            }
        });
    })
```

Here is the html to match the js:

```
        <div id="icon-wrapper">
            <div id="notes-icon" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></div>
            <div id="bg-left" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
            <div id="bg-right" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
            <div id="refresh" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></div>
            <div id="pin" class="icons"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="time-wrapper">
            <div id="time"></div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Create a note">
        </div>

        <div id="notes-wrapper">
            <div class="note">
               <span contenteditable="true"></span>
               <div class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the html

Comment: @DottedT sorry about that, added in html to go along

Comment: keyup is not cancelable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe forms are submitted on `keydown` so by the time your `keyup` event happens the form has already been submitted. Try changing it to

```js
$(this).on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body contenteditable>Change Me</body>
```

Comment: Are you suing a javascript plugin that would attach itself to the span tag?  If not then the span would need  contenteditable="true" as an attribute for this to work.  Try it out and let us know.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you, didn't realise you could do keydown keyup, thanks a lot!

Comment: And yep DottedT I had contenteditable=true as an attribute, wasn't using any plugins. Thanks for the help guys :)